# Как сделать поиск только в текущем каталоге без подкаталогов?

Tags: delphi

Какие правки, нужно внести в код, чтобы осуществлялся поиск только в текущем каталоге без подкаталогов?

```
procedure Scaserch(StartFolder, Mask: string; List: TStrings; ScanSubFolders: Boolean = True);
var
  SearchRec: TSearchRec;
  FindResult: Integer;
begin
  List.BeginUpdate;
  try
    StartFolder := IncludeTrailingBackslash(StartFolder);
    FindResult := FindFirst(StartFolder + '*.*', faAnyFile, SearchRec);
    try
      while FindResult = 0 do
        with SearchRec do
        begin
          if (Attr and faDirectory) <> 0 then
          begin
            if ScanSubFolders and (Name <> '.') and (Name <> '..') then
              Scaserch(StartFolder + Name, Mask, List, ScanSubFolders);
          end
          else
          begin
            if MatchesMask(Name, Mask) then
              List.Add(StartFolder + Name);
          end;
          FindResult := FindNext(SearchRec);
        end;
    finally
      FindClose(SearchRec);
    end;
  finally
    List.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Подключаю так:

```
Scaserch(SelectedFolder, '*.txt', ListBox1.Items);
```

Comment: Нужно разобраться, что в данном коде заставляет сканировать подкаталоги, и убрать это.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вашей функции есть параметр `ScanSubFolders` который управляет тем, будет ли производиться поиск в подпапках или нет. По-умолчанию, поиск в подпапках включён, чтобы выключить - передайте четвёртым параметром `False`:

```
Scaserch(SelectedFolder, '*.txt', ListBox1.Items, False);
```

Comment: Замечательный ответ, 20 минут я не мог понять в чем дело. Работает,  респект Вам zed.